# Handle click outside of chrome app window

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app, google-chrome-os

I need to hide some menu on Chrome App when user click outside of window,
Is there any way to handle mouse click outside of Chrome App window?
I know it's impossible by standard JavaScript API, but maybe Chrome API Provide something?

Answer (score 1):

A combination of window focus/blur

```
window.addEventListener("blur", function() { ... });
```

and

```
window.addEventListener("visibilitychange", function(newvisibility) { ... });
```

should be able to get you pretty much any info you need.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/User_experience/Using_the_Page_Visibility_API

Answer (score 0):

It is possible with regular javascript

```
addEventListener("focus",function() {
    windowFocus = true
})
addEventListener("blur",function() {
    windowFocus = false
})
```

Comment: This is working only for inside of document, but outside click doesn't considered as focus lose